# Is it better to use mains power or an external power supply for a rack mount unit?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, mains

I've seen many rack mount audio units that have an IEC connector for direct mains power, and others that have a DC jack for an external power supply (12V DC for example).

**What are the advantages and disadvantages of the mains vs. external power supply route? In terms of design difficulty, manufacturing cost, safety, etc.?**

From what I can tell, an external power supply would be easier for design of the unit and less expensive. And there are of course additional safety requirements for the mains voltage route. But I'm curious to know more specifics.

Comment: Ease of CE certification if you move out and outsource the power supply to a pre-approved COTS one.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage is that by buying an off-the-shelf external power supply, you out-source all the safety certification to someone else.  Your appliance runs on safe extra low voltage.

A second advantage is that the appliance can be smaller and lighter (excluding the power supply).

The down-side for the customer is that they get a nice neat rack of equipment, and hiding behind it is a terrible mess of power supplies and cables.

It's also impossible to provide a proper power switch on the equipment itself.  The power supply will be plugged in and turned on whether it's needed or not.